# How to find X value given Y value and show the point on a plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find a value in a plot that is generated using the following matlab function. I've tried using this z=find(y==0.0625); but it doesn´t seem to be working.

```
function con = funcCon (cMax)
% Time when the max concentration happens.
B = 3;
% mg to administer. 
A = (cMax / B) * exp(1);
% Time.
t = [1:50];
y(1,1) = 0;

for i = 2:50
    con = A*t(1,i)*exp(-t(1,i)/B);
    y(1,i) = con;
end 
plot(t,y)
end
```

Comment: I assume you mean to find the `t` for which y=0.0625?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you discretise `t` to be on the grid 1:50, you can only get the closest value that y has to 0.0625 from a  `t` in that grid.

This is found by:

```
[smallest_differance approx_t]=min(abs(y-0.0625) );
```

However if you want a more accurate solution you can write y as function of t:

```
y = @(t) abs ( A*t.*exp(-t./B)-0.0625);

t_solved = fminbnd(y,1,50)
```